# WPF Hide DataGridTemplateColumn when all values are empty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF datagrid with some columns. I have one column that will be empty most of the times. The column is filled with a small button.
The button has a visibility converter depending on a property to show/not show. So I want to be able to not show this column if the buttons are not shown.
Is it possible to do is in xaml?

Below is my code.

```
<DataGrid name="..." ItemsSource="...">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn ...
        <DataGridTextColumn ...
        <DataGridTextColumn ...
        <DataGridTextColumn ...
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                       <Button Visibility="{Binding IsShown Converter={StaticResource BooleanToCollapseConverter}}" Command="...">
                            <Image Source="...">
                            </Image>
                        </Button>
                   </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I Tried to set the width of the datagridtemplatecolumn to auto, but it didn't work.
One thing that will work is to check in code behind if my column needs to be empty and store this into a boolean to convert this to visibility.collapse.
But that has to be my last option.

Comment: Have you tried switching from `Auto` to `*`: You can try using  `<DataGrid name="..." ItemsSource="..." ColumnWidth="*">`

Comment: Yes, but it also didn't work and the columns do no have to be equally divided

Answer (score 3):

take a look at  [hide data grid template column when its empty](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/dfc6d020-24c0-4053-988f-43b7c3a8a1be/hide-data-grid-template-column-when-its-empty?forum=silverlightmvvm)

maybe this what you are looking for

Comment: Thx for the reply, but it is basicly the same as checking if the columns are empty from code behind

Comment: @Linnot wht do you mean , you mean in code behind you have to hide empty column ?

Comment: Checking each item in the itemssource to check if the column is empty or not and storing this check into a property.

Answer (score 0):

you're able to setup visibility directlty on the datagridtextcolumn or template. The thing is that these columns doesn't lie in visual tree of the datagrid which means that it does not inherit the datacontext of its parent. If you want to make sure that the binding is working you should create some kind of proxy that will inherit the datacontext from the parent control, for example:

```
<FrameworkElement x:Name="Proxy" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

anywhere inside the control that you're sure that has correct datacontext. This element will inherit it for sure. So .. getting straight to the point. I've made a small example for you to change visibility within bindings of your column:

```
<Grid>
    <FrameworkElement x:Name="Proxy" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Surname}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Age}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsShown, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, Source={x:Reference Proxy}}">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Test" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

IsShown property is on the view model side obviously. If you're not happy with this kind of solution you might try add different proxy client as follows:

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }
    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object),
                                     typeof(BindingProxy));
}


        ...
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <utils:BindingProxy x:Key="BindingProxy" Data="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        ...
```

using Freezable class - Freezable objects can inherit the DataContext even when they’re not in the visual or logical tree. So, we can take advantage of that to our use.